# Why must bluetoothd be stopped while using Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bleno

I have implemented a BLE peripheral. The device is based on Ubuntu OS.

My application runs under Node.js. It uses bleno (https://github.com/noble/bleno) to advertise its BLE service.

According to the read-me file at the site, in order to offer BLE services, daemon `bluetoothd` must be stopped and optionally disabled.

This statement seems to be true as my app works as expected only when this daemon has been stopped.

I am curious as to why must `bluetoothd` daemon be stopped. I couldn't find any explanation on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlueZ with bluetoothd is the built-in Bluetooth system for Linux that is the default. KDE and Gnome user utilities use this. There is also an API at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt for GATT.

Now, bleno is a "hack" that implements a Bluetooth host itself and therfore needs to completely take over the hci controller. In order not to interfere with bluetoothd, bluetoothd must be stopped.